# i'm trying to load a text file into an array. in vb

Tags: vb.net, file-io

this is what i have so far

the array size is (199,2)

the file holds lines that look like this: Canada,34026478,12938494
                                          USA,3377786,5345678

```
Sub LoadFromFile(filename As String)

    Dim Reader As StreamReader = File.OpenText(filename)
    Dim Currentline As String
    Dim lineArray() As String

    Do While Reader.EndOfStream = False
        Currentline = Reader.ReadLine
        lineArray = Currentline.Split(","c)
    Loop

    Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(filename)
        Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
            For Each c As Char In sr.ReadLine.Split
                Try
                    ValuesFromFile(y, x) = CStr(Integer.Parse(c))
                Catch ex As Exception 'i assume this is the only possible error, but we could be out of bounds due to assuming the actual size of the file/line... catch specific exceptions as necessary'
                End Try
                y += 1
            Next
            x += 1
            y = 0
        Loop
    End Using



    Reader.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you read the file twice?

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: You haven't described any problem you're having with the code you posted. What specific question are you asking here?